# How do I synchronize an existing local directory and an existing remote git repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a local directory and a remote git repository. Both contain the same files. However, the local directory is not yet connected to the remote repo. How can I connect them? The commands I have tried so far did not work because the local directory is not empty.

Not sure if this makes a difference but the local folder and the remote repo do not have the same names.

Comment: What commands did you try? Please put them to your question.

Answer (score 4):

`git remote set-url origin //path/to/repo.git`

and either

`git pull origin [your branch]` or `git push origin [your branch]`

Comment: I'm getting error "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" Is that because my local directory is not yet a git branch? If so, how do i make it one?

Comment: that error sounds like the path you entered wasn't a valid git repo. double-check that path. you can check if you are in a branch by typing `git status`.

Comment: Hm, I checked it by entering "git remote -v" and I used the output of that. So like this:

    `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo.git`

Comment: make sure you include `https://` in the path. so `https://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo.git`

Comment: I did. It wasn't visible in my comment above at first because I forgot the quotes to display it as code but I fixed it. I entered it with the https://. Just to be clear, because I'm dense, on the command line I am inside the local directory that I want to link up to the existing git repo. However, the local directory is not yet a repo itself. It contains no .git folder. Do I have to initialize it first for `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo.git` to be successful?

Comment: oh, yes. you're going to have to make it into a git repo for that to work. you may want to clone the remote repo first and then copy your files to that folder. the cloned repo will already be setup

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly but I think what you are saying is exactly the issue I am trying to solve. I can't change anything about the local directory. It's a local directory that contains files. I can't move/remove/rename either the directory or the files contained within it. I have to connect it in its current state to the remote repo, which contains the identical files as the local directory. So I guess this would be a 2 step process: Initialize the local directory to be a git repo and then connect it to the remote.

Comment: Put a bit more succinctly, how do I init the local directory to become a git repo in a way that it can be connected to the remote repo without causing conflicts?

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm not sure what you're asking is possible. Can you even `git init` in this directory? Can you not touch this directory or its files in any meaningful way?

Comment: It seems like I cannot. The directory lives on a server that I am remote desktopping into. I just tried to run `git init` on it and I am getting a `Permission denied` reply. I checked the permissions and I have full `rwx` permissions on the directory but I am still not able to initialize git on it or even copy files into it. I am not a server admin and if something is going on that can't be fixed with changing perm levels on the command line - as it seems it does - then this is above my skill level. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you want to link two **local** directories, of which one is already a git clone:

```
cd your/NOT/git/clone/dir
git init .
git remote add origin http...
git fetch -p --all
```

And to really "link" you two directories, you could even add a local remote:

```
git remote add file:///path/to/original/local/clone
```